# Map tab separated file with a list using awk/sed/join

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have multiple large files with two columns (tab-delimited).
The content of these files are like this:

working_file-1

```
K00001 0.188
K00005 15.97
K00008 188.09
```

mapping file

```
K00001
K00002 
K00003
K00004
K00005
K00006 
K00007
K00008
```

mapping file range is K00001 - K25804

I want to map my working_file-1 to mapping file so that the output looks like this:

```
K00001 0.188
K00002 
K00003
k00004
K00005 15.97
K00006 
K00007
k00008 188.09
```

The blanks (K0's not present in working_file) can be filled with zero (if possible) or can be left as blank.

So far, I tried these codes by following other similar posts (but did not success):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' mapping file working_file-1 > output.file

grep -Fw -f mapping file working_file-1 > output.file
```

edit: output of od -c work1; od -c map

```
0000000   K   0   0   0   0   1  \r  \n   K   0   0   0   0   2  \r  \n
0000020   K   0   0   0   0   3  \r  \n   K   0   0   0   0   4  \r  \n
0000040   K   0   0   0   0   5  \r  \n   K   0   0   0   0   6  \r  \n
0000060   K   0   0   0   0   7  \r  \n   K   0   0   0   0   8  \r  \n
```

Comment: `sort -rf "mapping file" working_file-1 | awk '$1==p{next} !$2{$2=0} {p=$1} 1' | tac > output.file`

Comment: Is there a significance to the mixture of lower-case and upper-case K's?  Is the match case-sensitive or case-insensitive?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry. those are all upper case..my typing mistake.

Comment: Should K00087, K00105, K00118, K01206 appear in the output for the inputs shown?  Will every number in `working_file-1` appear in the mapping file?  Are both input files in sorted order of Kxxxxx numbers?

Comment: @jhnc. yes. sorry. edited now

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. yes. the mapping file range is K00001 - K25804.  Want all K0s from mapping file followed by those mapped from working_file-1 (unmapped K0s with blanks or filled with zero). input files are sorted in order of increasing K0's (Though have missing K0's in working file).Thanks

Comment: `join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 "mapping file" working_file-1 > output.file` (if both files are already sorted)

Comment: @jhnc the Join command did not work. just gave one column with all K0's from mapping file followed by 0s. Your command (sort -rf...) works in mapping, but the output is showing mapped K0's (from working_file-1) as well as K0's from mapping file and 0s in one column.

Comment: try `... | awk -v OFS='\t' ... | ...` or `join -t $'\t' ...` (if bash)

Comment: @jhnc whats the . . . in the command . Do indeed to replace it with my files. can use bash. When used as it is, it throws syntex error for . . .  . The sort -rf "mapping file" working_file-1 | awk '$1==p{next} {p=$1} 1' | tac > output.file worked well. Is there any way to not to include duplicate K0s (as it outputs mapped K0s from both file in one column). Thanks

Comment: @jhnc my bash throws syntex error for ellipse in the command

Comment: @jhnc Thanks (novice mistake from my side. sorry). Combining the first command with awk -v OFS='\t' did work in properly indenting the numericals including 0's (into the second column). but still, the problem of repeated K0's exist in column 1. This is not a big issue as I can remove repeated K0s . Combining the join command with the earlier join did not work. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "repeated K0's". I cut&pasted the examples you gave into test files. If my code didn't work on your actual files, they probably don't match what you've shown. Or else your problem needs restating. By the way, why does `K00003 0.188` appear in input but `K00001 0.188` appears in output? And why do `K00087 0.188`, etc, not appear in the output?

Comment: @K00003 0.188 was an editing mistake. the other K0 did not show in the above output because then have to write all from K00001, K00002, K00003. ....... K01206.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a "map" file like:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

and a "work1" file like:

```
a A
c C
g G
```

and desired "merged1" output like:

```
a A
b
c C
d
e
f
g G
h
```

then `join` can do the combining:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -o 0,2.2 map work1 > merged1
```

- `-1 1 -2 1` joins on first (space-delimited) field of each file
- `-a 1` prints lines from first file even if unpaired
- `-o 0,2.2` formats output to be join field (first column), separator (space), then second field of second file

---

To produce instead "merged2" like:

```
a A
b 0
c C
d 0
e 0
f 0
g G
h 0
```

add the `-e` option:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 map work1 > merged2
```

---

If "work2" has fields separated by a character other than single space, use the `-t` option.

For example, with "work2" using single tab delimiter like:

```
a   A
c   C
g   G
```

(note: stackoverflow displays this with spaces instead of single tab) then with POSIX shell, use `-t '  '` (ie. QUOTE TAB QUOTE - may need to be typed as: <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> if shell performs history completion):

```
join -t '   ' -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 map work2 >merged3
```

or with bash, using `-t $'\t'` is possible instead:

```
join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 map work2 >merged3
```

to produce "merged3" like:

```
a   A
b   0
c   C
d   0
e   0
f   0
g   G
h   0
```

(note: again stackoverflow displays the tab as spaces)

Comment: Really thanks for putting it down so nicely. but somehow it did not work. with join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 map work1 > merged2 the output is K00001
 
K00002
 
K00003 ....     with join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o 0,2.2 map work2 >merged3 the output is K00001
 0
K00002
 0
K00003 0 .....

Comment: @Shail what OS are you using? Take your new examples from your question and run the join command - does that work? If not, run `od -c work1; od -c map` on the new files you just made and add the output to your question. If it does work, then try `od -c realwork | less` or something on your actual file and check its format matches the test version.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. somehow missed seeing it.  I copied the example file from here to a new file and ran the join command (both). apparently, it did not work. i have attached the output of od -c work1; od -c map above. I am on CentOS Linux 7

Comment: Your file appears to contain DOS-style line endings. Try installing `dos2unix`. You can either overwrite the original files directly (`dos2unix file1 file2`) or create new files (`dos2unix -n in.file out.file`, etc). Then run the `join` command on the new files. Afterwards, you might need to run `unix2dos mergedfile` to make that also have DOS format

Comment: Thanks. problem solved. Indeed it was a file format issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sort` for `-s` (stable sort) this might be what you want:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -u -s working_file-1 mapping_file
K00001  0.188
K00002
K00003
K00004
K00005  15.97
K00006
K00007
K00008  188.09
```

or if you want to add `0`s:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -u -s working_file-1 mapping_file |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2+=0}'
K00001  0.188
K00002  0
K00003  0
K00004  0
K00005  15.97
K00006  0
K00007  0
K00008  188.09
```

If you don't have GNU sort then you could do:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2rn working_file-1 mapping_file |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 != p{print $1, $2+0; p=$1}'
K00001  0.188
K00002  0
K00003  0
K00004  0
K00005  15.97
K00006  0
K00007  0
K00008  188.09
```

Comment: Fixed. The aim of the mapping file is, I have a bunch of working files with random K0's (all in the range from K00001 to K25804). Some of the K0's present in one working file are missing in another. I want to join this bunch of working files by  adding 0 to missing K0's to get uniform table.

Comment: my  Bash threw error saying  "Isolated character in block: invalid block specification '1,1u' ".  when using sort -k1,1u -s working_file-1 mapping_file

Comment: Perhaps `-k1,1u` should be `-k1,1 -u`.  Although this could in theory work with any [POSIX sort](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) that has `-s`, POSIX does not seem to define which of multiple "unique" lines will be printed. GNU and FreeBSD versions seem to work as Ed expects but [busybox](https://busybox.net/) prints both lines anyway (which I think may be a bug).

Comment: @jhnc yes, it should be `-k1,1 -u`, fixed now thanks. And yes, without `-s` you could get any of the lines with duplicate keys output.

Comment: @Shail you said in your question that adding 0 was optional and it's not present in your expected output. If you need it then fix the text and example in your question.

Comment: Don't you mean `-s` is for stable sort? `-u` is for uniq'ing - which is what posix doesn't seem to define re selecting which "unique" line to output when they aren't identical (as in this case).

Comment: btw, GNU coreutils info page implies `-s` is redundant when `-u` is used (and source code seems to agree). source comments confusingly state both "Only the last of a sequence of equal lines will be output." and " output only the first of an identical series of lines."

Comment: @jhnc I'm sorry, I don't understand [the first of your last 2 comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815233/map-tab-separated-file-with-a-list-using-awk-sed-join/67818075?noredirect=1#comment119882864_67818075), I don't see anywhere I used `-u` when I meant `-s` or vice-versa. Good to know that `-u` implies `-s` for GNU sort.

Comment: @jhnc Ah, yes, that was a mistake. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. This works better in mapping and giving the desired output. only this is it gives repeated K0's for the matched field. e.g. K00001 K00001 (both in 1st column)  0.188 (2nd column) K00003 0 K00004 0 K00005 K00005 15.97

Comment: No it doesn't as you can see in my answer. Maybe the input file you're running it on has extraneous white space or control chars at the end of your data lines. Try `cat -Ev` on each of your input file to see if any unexpected characters are present.

Comment: @EdMorton There is $ at the end of every line e.g. K00003  995$
K00012  48$
K00013  714$
K00014  32$
Is that might be the issue?

Comment: No, that `$` is the expected/required "end of line" indicator.

Comment: That's strange to get a different result from yours. anyways, most of the desired output I can get from your above command. I filtered out the  K0s (repeated) without any value in the second column from the output. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely something you should not ignore and instead investigate til you figure out what's causing the problem because it will almost certainly cause you more problems in the future if your data isn't what you think it is or the tools on your system are broken or you're copy/pasting things wrong. SOunds like you're also having trouble running `join` so some issue with your data files seems most likely but I can't imagine what it'd be - you''d have to apply divide-and-conquer or similar to pin-point where the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. It was a file format issue. As suggested by @jhnc I changed the file format and now the join and awk command works perfectly.